# Creating a high pass filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create a high pass filter in Matlab. I generate the Gaussian Kernel using

```
function kernel = compute_kernel(sigma,size)
[x,y] = meshgrid(-size/2:size/2,-size/2:size/2);
constant = 1/(2*pi*sigma*sigma);
kernel = constant*exp( -(y.^2 + x.^2 )/(2 * sigma * sigma));
kernel = (kernel - min(kernel(:)))./(max(kernel(:)) - min(kernel(:)));
end
```

Then after creating the Kernel I use it to create a low pass filter for the image(variable `im2` ):

```
g = compute_kernel(9,101);
im2_low = conv2(im2,g,'same');
```

As I understand I can then use subtract the filtered image from the original image(in the frequency domain) to extract the high frequencies making it the equivalent of a high pass filter.

```
F = fft2(im2_low);
IM2 = fft2(im2);
IM2_high = IM2 - F;

figure; fftshow(IM2_high);
im2_high = ifft2(IM2_high);
figure; imshow(im2_high,[]);
```

There seems to be something wrong with this though. When I view the high pass filtered image it seems to a color inverted blurred image not the ones with the edges defined as I've seen online. I'm not sure if my process is wrong or whether I'm just using the wrong values for my Gaussian Kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any kernel that you want to use for maintaining image features (i.e. you don't want a magnitude of something, but the image to look as human recognizable image) you need to make sure you do a thing to the kernel: normalize it.

You seem to have tried that, but you misinterpreted the meaning of normalizing in kernels. The don't need to be [0-1], their **sum** needs to be 1.

So, taking your code:

```
im2=imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png');
im2=double(rgb2gray(im2));

sigma=9;
sizei=101;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-sizei/2:sizei/2,-sizei/2:sizei/2);
constant = 1/(2*pi*sigma*sigma);
kernel = constant*exp( -(y.^2 + x.^2 )/(2 * sigma * sigma));
%%%%%% NORMALIZATION
kernel=kernel/sum(kernel(:));
%%%%%%

im2_low = conv2(im2,kernel,'same');

F = fft2(im2_low);
IM2 = fft2(im2);
IM2_high = IM2 - F;


im2_high = ifft2(IM2_high);
figure; imshow(im2_high,[]);
```

[image]

But, as CrisLuengo mentions, subtraction is an operation that doesn't change in the Fourier domain, thus the answer is

```
im2_high=im2-im2_low
```

Comment: Trying this now. Thanks.

Comment: @user3927312 to convince yourself, try to plot your `im2_low` with a colorbar, and check the values of the extrema. Both images should be in the same range if you want to add/subtract them meaningfully.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you meant in the comment above though. If you could explain a bit more it would help. I'm new to Image Processing, as you can tell.

Comment: literally that. Do `figure();imshow(im2_low,[]);colorbar;figure();imshow(im2,[]);colorbar;f` just after you computed your kernel. Note the values of the colorbar. In your case, the low pass filter was in the thousands, while the riginal iamge only goes to 255. If you want to maintain the range of values, your kernels need to be normalized to add up to 1.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Subtraction in the Fourier domain is identical to subtraction in the spatial domain. The calls to `fft` and `ifft` are superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

*This is a long answer to a short question. Read it if you want to learn something.*

A low-pass filter and a high-pass filter are both linear filters.
A linear filter can be applied in the spatial domain through a convolution or in the frequency domain (a.k.a. Fourier domain) as a multiplication.

It is true that, in the Fourier domain, the difference between a low-pass filter kernel and a identity filter (all-pass filter) is a high-pass filter:

> ```
> high_pass_filter = identity_filter - low_pass_filter
> ```

The identity filter would be a kernel where every element is 1. The filter isapplied by multiplication, so

> ```
> IM2 * high_pass_filter = IM2 * ( identity_filter - low_pass_filter )
> ```

which is the same as

> ```
> IM2 * high_pass_filter = IM2 - IM2 * low_pass_filter
> ```

(here, as in the question, `IM2` is the Fourier-domain representation of the image `im2`; all the stuff with the yellow borders are meant to be equations but are written in pseudo-code, with the `*` symbol used for multiplication).

Thus, the OP wants to apply a low-pass filter and subtract the input image in the Fourier domain to obtain a high-pass--filtered image.

However, one of the [properties of the Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties) is that it is a linear transform. This means that

> ```
> F(a*f + b*g) == a * F(f) + b * F(g)
> ```

(with `F(.)` the Fourier transform, `a` and `b` constants, and `f` and `g` functions). Setting `a=1` and `b=-1`, and `g` the low-pass--filtered image and `f` the input image, we get

> ```
> F(im2 - im2_low) == F(im2) - F(im2_low)
> ```

That is, subtraction in the spatial domain and in the Fourier domain are equivalent. Thus, if one computes `im2_low` in the spatial domain, there is no need to go to the Fourier domain for the subtraction. These two bits of code produce an identical result (up to numerical precision):

```
F = fft2(im2_low);
IM2 = fft2(im2);
IM2_high = IM2 - F;
im2_high = ifft2(IM2_high);

im2_high = im2 - im2_low;
```

Furthermore, the convolution is linear also. This means that, if you think of `F(.)` in the equations above as a convolution, those equations still hold. You can do manipulations like this:

> ```
> conv(f, h) - f == conv(f, h) - conv(f, 1) == conv(f, h-1)
> ```

**This directly leads to a definition of a high-pass filter in the spatial domain:**

```
g = - compute_kernel(9,101);
g(51,51) = g(51,51) + 1;
im2_high2 = conv2(im2,g,'same');
```

You will see that `max(max(abs(im2_high-im2_high2)))` yields a value very close to 0.

---

**A note regarding computing the Gaussian filter:**

The `compute_kernel` function posted in the question computes a 2D filter kernel by directly evaluating a 2D Gaussian. The resulting filter kernel is 101x101 pixels, meaning that computing the convolution requires `101 * 101 * N` multiplications and additions (MADs), with `N` the number of pixels in the filtered image. However, the Gaussian filter is separable, meaning that the same result can be obtained in only `101 * 2 * N` MADs (50x fewer!). Additionally, for `sigma = 9` one can get away with a smaller kernel too.

1. Gaussian kernel size:

   The Gaussian function never reaches zero, but it reaches very close to zero quite quickly. When cutting it off at `3*sigma`, very little of it is lost. I find 3 sigma to be a good balance. In the case of sigma = 9, the 3 sigma cutoff leads to a kernel with 55 pixels (3*sigma * 2 + 1).
2. Gaussian separability:

   The multi-dimensional Gaussian can be obtained by multiplying 1D Gaussians together:

   > ```
   > exp(-(y.^2+x.^2)/(2*sigma*sigma)) == exp(-(x.^2)/(2*sigma*sigma)) * exp(-(y.^2)/(2*sigma*sigma))
   > ```

   This leads to a much more efficient implementation of the convolution:

   > ```
   > conv(f,h1*h2) == conv( conv(f,h1), h2 )
   > ```

   That is, convolving an image with a column filter `h1` and then convolving the result with a row filter `h2` is the same as convolving the image with a 2D filter `h1*h2`. In code:

   ```
   sigma = 9;
   sizei = ceil(3*sigma); % 3 sigma cutoff
   g = exp(-(-sizei:sizei).^2/(2*sigma.^2)); % 1D Gaussian kernel
   g = g/sum(g(:)); % normalize kernel
   im2_low = conv2(g,g,im2,'same');

   g2d = g' * g;
   im2_low2 = conv2(im2,g2d,'same');
   ```

   The difference is numerical imprecision:

   ```
   max(max(abs(im2_low-im2_low2)))
   ```

   > ```
   > ans =
   >    1.3927e-12
   > ```

You'll find [a more detailed description about Gaussian filtering](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22) on my blog, as well as [some issues you can run into when using MATLAB's Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/150).

Comment: Fantastic answer.